# How to create Subdomains pointing to different folders in a web server?

Tags: tomcat, iis, angularjs, webserver, domain-aliasing

This may be basic but not able to find right answer so far.
My requirement:

- 1. I will have a domain --> http://www.mydomain.com and it points to a
     folder called say - \landing
  2. I will have multiple customers
  3. As they register to us, I want to create routes like customer1.mydomain.com, customer2.mydomain.com
  4. I want customer1.mydomain.com point to \landing\customer1 and so forth

I shall have an html5/angularjs app running in each folder which will hold each customer context and various other resources.
Webserver preferably = IIS8 (for Win) or Apache Tomcat (for linux)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

with apache you could write a .htacces file from a PHP script using mod_rewrite. However the processing time is going to up on the server for every rewrite rule you make from your php script.

Comment: I won't be using php in server. We are going to use plain html5 with angularjs SPA and should be treated as static site.
I can actually run it like mydomain.com/customer1 as of now and it works ... wanted to become more elegant :)